why does my shopify image-picker not work?
I'm trying to create an image with text section in Shopify. I added arrows left and right as picture to be able to change the image when clicking on the arrows. So i have 4 image-picker in total : image 1, image2, arrow left, arrow right.
Do you understand why image picker 1 and 2 are working but image picker 3 and 4 ( arrows ) are not even asking me to select images. Is there a limitation to the number of image picker one can use in a section ?
Here is the .liquid file without css ( tell me if you need the css to understand the issue ):
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Anim'Sport",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "label": "Title",
      "id": "title",
      "default": "blabla"
    },
    {
      "type": "textarea",
      "label": "Description",
      "id": "description",
      "default": "blabla"
    },
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "label": "Image 1",
      "id": "image_1"
    },
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "label": "Image 2",
      "id": "image_2"
    },
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "label": "Left Arrow Image",
      "id": "left_arrow_image"
    },
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "label": "Right Arrow Image",
      "id": "right_arrow_image"
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Anim'Sport"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}

<div class="animsport-container" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="animsport-text">
        <h1>{{ section.settings.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ section.settings.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="animsport-images-container">
        <img src="{{ section.settings.image_1 | img_url }}" alt="Image 1" class="animsport-images-album" id="current-image" />
        
        
        <img src="{{ section.settings.right_arrow_image | img_url }}" alt="Arrow Right" class="animsport-arrow-right" id="right-arrow" />
        <img src="{{ section.settings.left_arrow_image | img_url }}" alt="Arrow Left" class="animsport-arrow-left" id="left-arrow" />
    </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const images = [
        "{{ section.settings.image_1 | img_url }}", 
        "{{ section.settings.image_2 | img_url }}"
    ];

    let currentIndex = 0; 

    const imageElement = document.getElementById('current-image');
    const leftArrow = document.getElementById('left-arrow');
    const rightArrow = document.getElementById('right-arrow');

    function changeImage() {
        imageElement.src = images[currentIndex];
    }

    rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length; 
        changeImage();
    });

    leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + images.length) % images.length; 
        changeImage();
    });
});
</script>



Well i don't know the answer but i just changed arrows pictures with css arrows it should work.

Better suited to be a comment/edit to the original question, as it states "don't know the answer", so it's not really an answer.
